# Upload de 2 arquivos através de ashx

Tags: javascript, c#, twitter-bootstrap, file-upload, ashx

Tenho a tela abaixo:

[image]

Preciso que o usuário selecione uma música e uma capa, porém não estou achando uma maneira de enviar os dois arquivos de uma só vez e ainda validar se foi selecionado a Música e a Capa.

Até então segui o exemplo abaixo, porém o JS pega apenas o conteúdo do input de Foto **(upFoto)**, entretanto criei o mesmo trecho com nomes diferentes para pegar o input de Música **(upMusica)**, porém o JS não envia arquivo MP3, ocorre erro no click do botão enviar **(lbtEnviar)**.

Alguém teria uma sugestão para este caso?

```
$(function () {
        $('#lbtEnviar').click(function () {
            var fileUpload = $("#upFoto").get(0);
            var files = fileUpload.files;
            var test = new FormData();
            for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                test.append(files[i].name, files[i]);
            }
            $.ajax({
                url: "UploadArquivo.ashx",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                data: test,
                // dataType: "json",
                success: function (result) {
                    alert(result);
                },
                error: function (err) {
                    alert(err.statusText);
                }
            });
        });
    })
```

Trecho em C# que recebe o arquivo:

```js
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            try
            {
                if (context.Request.Files.Count > 0)
                {
                    HttpFileCollection files = context.Request.Files;
                    for (int i = 0; i < files.Count; i++)
                    {
                        HttpPostedFile file = files[i];
                        string fname;
                        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser.Browser.ToUpper() == "IE" || HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser.Browser.ToUpper() == "INTERNETEXPLORER")
                        {
                            string[] testfiles = file.FileName.Split(new char[] { '\\' });
                            fname = testfiles[testfiles.Length - 1];
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            fname = file.FileName;
                        }

                        string pathToSave = "D:\\Msik_Arquivos" + "\\" + fname;
                        file.SaveAs(pathToSave);
                    }
                }
                context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
                context.Response.Write("File Uploaded Successfully!");
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Optei por outra solução sem o uso do JavaScript, estou utilizando um componente FileUpload e configurei o click do botão para enviar o arquivo a pasta que precisava:

```html
<asp:FileUpload ID="fupFoto" runat="server"/>

<asp:LinkButton ID="lbtEnviar" type="submit" runat="server" OnClick="lbtEnviar_Click">Enviar</asp:LinkButton>
```

No eventro click do botão enviar configurei o trecho abaixo:

```js
if (fupMusica.HasFile)
{
  string extensaoMusica = Path.GetExtension(fupMusica.FileName);
  if (extensaoMusica == ".mp3")
  {
    try
    {
      string nomeMusica = fupMusica.FileName;
      string pathToSave = "D:\\Musicas_Arquivos" + "\\" + nomeMusica;
      fupMusica.SaveAs(pathToSave);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    { // ERRO AO SALVAR }
  }
  else
  { // ESCOLHA UM ARQUIVO MP3 }
}
else
{ // NÃO FOI SELECIONADO NENHUM ARQUIVO }
```

Por padrão só é possível fazer 4MB de upload, sendo assim tive que alterar no Web.config as propriedades maxAllowedContentLength, executionTimeout, maxRequestLength.